# Mongoengine queryset only + to_json/as_pymongo missing id

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Taking this example:

```
>>> class Doc(Document):
...    foo = StringField()
...    bar = StringField()
```

If I want the "bar" field:

```
>>> Doc(foo='foo', bar='bar').save()
>>> Doc.objects.only('bar').to_json()
'[{"bar": "bar"}]'
```

If I want the "id" field and "bar":

```
>>> Doc.objects.only('id', 'bar').to_json()
'[{"bar": "bar"}]'
```

Is this intentional or a bug?

BTW, I mentioned `as_pymongo` because to_json uses it.

EDIT: removed a useless question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '_id' instead on 'id'.

Background: MongoDb calls it's internal "primary key" "_id" to avoid namespace conflicts (so that you can have a field called "id" for instance) and to denote that it is a mongodb internal... some ORMS use mongo_id for direct access to that "_id" item. But, yeah, it's to avoid namespace issues with the very common field name "id". In the context of your query you are doing a literal mongodb call, so it needs to be '_id' as that is it's real name.

Edited..

Comment: In the MongoDB database itself, all documents' unique ids are the "_id" field. So it's not a MongoEngine quirk, it's a faithful reflection of the data.

Comment: True, I was sort of babbling in the answer. Mongodb actually calls that field '_id'.